# how to start a process and get it's MainWindowHandle in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winapi

i wan to create a application that can start a process when page load, and a button to hide and show the process.

```
  Dim a As Integer
  a = Process.Start("notepad.exe").Handle.ToInt32
  ShowWindow(a, SW_HIDE)
```

i only can start the process, but cannot hide it.
any miss take in my code??

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a main window in native win32. A process can have zero, one or several "main" windows.

To find and show/hide windows in another process you need to enumerate the windows and compare the process id of the window with the process id of the process you started...

Comment: That's technically true, but not practically.  Windows sometimes needs to guess at the main window handle, Taskmgr.exe is a good example.  It is exposed in .NET by Process.MainWindowHandle.  Doesn't always work but works very often, certainly with notepad.

Comment: Hmm, after checking you're right, it uses EnumWindows().  Doesn't look like the OP is really interested, +1 and I'll delete my post.